# Automatic Solar light far too dim, help with increasing brightness

Tags: transistors, components, solar-cell

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fbX5Ey.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I've built a simple circuit that uses a transistor to switch from charging 2AA batteries during the day to discharging the batteries to power 3 white LEDs at night.

In order to fully power the 3 LEDs, I plan to add a third AA. (as shown in diagram above)
How would I change the components, specifically R1 and R2, to handle this increased voltage and fully illuminate the lights. 
Also, are there any other pressing concerns that would effect the brightness that I should fix and how?

thanks for the help!

Comment: Transistor cannot supply current more than 10 mA for the LEDs. Go for a one similar to BC817-25. Reduce R1 so that base current (Vin - Vbe)/R1 is sufficiently large to cause sufficient collector current.

Comment: In your circuit, I am wondering how the transistor is turning on. Voltage at the emitter pin should be greater than voltage at the base pin..in your case it's 3.6 V and 6 V. Doesn't make sense to me.. Correct me if i am wrong

Comment: The current from solar panel is rushing into the 3.6 V battery

Comment: @Umar 3906 can source over 100mA no problems.

Comment: As far as the problems to solving components, Bruce's answer has all of it. With regards to solar cell and batteries: This will become problematic. This solar cell you specify has a peak voltage of 6V. It will _not_ care about the charge state of the batteries and keep supplying current until the batteries reach a voltage at or above the peak voltage = way too much. You _must_ include protection for your batteries or they will overcharge, heat and leak.

Answer (score 2):

R2 sets the current through the LEDs. It must soak up the voltage difference between the supply and the LEDs. A typical 5mm super-bright white LED drops about 3.3V at 20mA. A 3.6V AA NiMH battery should deliver between 4.2V and 3.3V depending on state of charge, with an average of about 3.8V. The transistor will drop about 0.1V in saturation, leaving ~0.4V across R2. With 3 LEDs consuming 20mA each the total current is 60mA, so the resistance required is 0.4V/0.06A = 6.7 Ohms (a 6.8Ω resistor will be close enough). If you want a lower LED current then insert that into the formula.

If the LEDs are not well matched you may find that they do not draw equal current in parallel. This issue can be avoided by splitting R2 into 3 resistors which feed each LED separately. The value of each resistor must then be 3 times higher than the total, eg. 20Ω (use the nearest 5% value, 18Ω or 22Ω).

R1 sets the Base current of Q1. It should supply sufficient current to saturate the transistor, so that it can switch full battery voltage to the output at the required current. Collector current is amplified by the 2N3906's current gain (Beta or Hfe) which in normal operation is between 60 and 300. However in saturation the current gain is reduced, so a lower Collector/Base current ratio may be required (eg. 20:1).

The value of R1 can be calculated in the same manner as for R2 (determine voltage across resistor, apply Ohm's Law). However that reveals a problem with your circuit. A 6V solar panel usually has 12 cells in series, supplying ~0.5V each. In the dark each cell acts like a silicon diode, so the panel is effectively 12 diodes in series. When powered externally the diode action will drop ~0.5V per cell, for a total of 6V. This is higher than the NiMH battery voltage, but your circuit needs a lower voltage (preferably zero Volts) to turn on the transistor. It only works due to leakage current in the solar panel, which is not defined and drops to zero as the panel voltage approaches zero.

If you try to increase Q1's Base current by reducing the value of R1 then you may be limited by the panel's dark current. To guarantee sufficient Base current you can wire a resistor across the panel. The combined value of  this resistor (let's call it R3) and R1 then sets Q1's Base current. Assuming 3.8V from the battery, 0.6V across Q1 Emitter-Base, and 60mA/20 = 3mA Base current, R1+R3 = (3.8V-0.6V)/3mA = 1067Ω. Splitting that value into equal resistances gives 534Ω per resistor (470Ω will be close enough). R3 will waste about 12mA of potential charging current, but this should not be significant.

In bright sunlight the panel can deliver up to 330mA charging current. This may be slightly above the recommended trickle current for AA cells (eg. 200mA for a 2000mAh cell) however this high current is unlikely to cause damage as it will only occur for an hour or so in the middle of the day.